# Firefox: error on middle-clicking a toolbar button

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

```
function scrollToPos(activeTab, clickData)
{
    if (clickData.button === 0)
        browser.tabs.executeScript({ code: scrollToTopOrBack, runAt: "document_end" });
    else
        browser.tabs.executeScript({ code: "window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);" });
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(scrollToPos);
```

On middle-clicking the button, the `else` command is not executed and I get the "Missing host permission for the tab" error.

If I first **left-click** the button and then middle-click, the `else` command **is** executed with no error.

What's going on? How can I fix that?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the browser. Could be also a timing problem: try waiting a bit more before clicking.

Comment: Waiting does not change anything. Thank you.

Comment: The problem seems to occur only when using "browser.tabs.executeScript". Is it possible to to use "window.scrollTo" in a different way?

Comment: The code is incomplete. Where is `scrollToTopOrBack`?

Comment: The code for `scrollToTopOrBack` is on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scroll-to-top-and-back/.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `"<all_urls>"` permission solves the problem.